# DNS, why is it sometimes doing a PTR lookup before A lookup?

Tags: domain-name-system, wireshark

When I perform NSLOOKUP -q=a chinaa.cn I get the following result in WireShark:

[image]

Why did it FIRST look up the PTR of my ISP DNS before sending an A-request?
And why did the DNS server respond first with with No such name with .home-appended to it?

Comment: Probably so it can log which DNS server it used to do the lookup.

Comment: @hardillb nope, because it only does this rarely

Comment: Edit the question to show what's in your `/etc/resolve.conf`

Comment: @hardillb , what's the windows-equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSLOOKUP` first displays the IP address of the DNS server it sends the request to, along with its DNS name. If the DNS name is not already in the DNS cache, then it sends a PTR request to get the name.

[image]

Comment: And the reason it only does it intermittently is because it will be caching the response for the TTL. The answer to the second question will be because your DHCP server will be returning `.home` as a search path so it will checked first